# Hide POST/GET requests - Flash & PHP

Tags: php, flash, security

I'm currently working with a friend on a flash game. 
He want's to insert the scores inside a database when the player finishes the game. 
He's using this tutorial for the flash - http://www.tizag.com/flashTutorial/flashforms.php . 
The swf he made works great - it posts the data. The problem is I can see the request from firebug. This opens up another problem - any more advanced user may insert a score of his own without playing the game...

So is there a way to hide the requests made from the flash game? 
What would be the right approach to this problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, there is no way to actually hide the requests made. That is impossible, not only can firebug or Live HTTP Headers intercept it if it is run in a web browser, I can load up Wireshark and find all incoming and outgoing traffic and analyse it. What you need is a method of encryption or offuscation. For example, take their score, base64_encode() it, then take the current time, reverse it (and maybe add a key to the end of it), and then take the MD5 of that. Submit all three pieces of info to the server, if the time is more than 5 seconds old, they could have edited the request and sent a false one. Check the validity of the time by reversing it (and then adding the key to it if you used one) and taking the MD5 and make sure they match. Of course, you can run some complex encryption algorithm, but that is pointless in the end:

There IS no foolproof way to combat this. I used to work in the reverse engineering field. I can tell you that I can edit any value in any flash game. Therefore, while the submission of the score may be somewhat secure, I can decompile your game and look at the code, and see what you did to offuscate the score submission. Or, even easier, I can just edit the value that holds the score in probably under 60 seconds. Adobe Flash Player stores variables in memory, and that is where the weakness is, I can edit those variables and values in memory easily.

And if you are trying to take on the challenge of preventing reverse engineering, I say you just stop at the offuscation and hope no one like me is playing your game. Many many attempts have been done to prevent reverse engineering, and let me just say this: offuscation and "security" only keeps the honest guys out. This is true for both the real world as well as programming. Someone that truely wants to exploit a system and has the skills to do so, it is easy. It only keeps casual hackers and cheaters from cheating. The balance between security and methods to circumvent it is ever close to equilibrium.

Comment: I'm trying only to prevent cheating. What would you recommend to stop people from cheating by simply doing POST to myScript.php ?

Comment: No, POST and GET are the same to me. Both are easily intercepted.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to protect your game as long as the control resides on the client. The dumber the client is, the better chance you have at securing the high scores.

We start out with the simplest approach: the client submits a score at the end of the game. You can use whatever tricky encryption method you want, but a cheater could simply adjust the stored score in memory. He doesn't even need to know how you are encrypting the data.

Even if you do this periodically throughout gameplay, it doesn't really matter. The server could try to estimate that there's no way for a high score to be valid given the time constraints, but at some point you end up with a score that is close enough to valid that you cannot discard it.

Cheaters can also alter the game to give themselves an unfair advantage. Say part of the game revolves being able to guess which door the treasure is behind. All they have to do is hack the game to show them that data. They don't even have to modify the score generating code... because they've made the game itself easier.

The only way to securely get around this on an untrusted platform is to offload the important parts of the gameplay to the server itself. The client becomes a dumb terminal of sorts, doing whatever it is told. The server keeps track of the high score in real time based on the client's actions. You cannot cheat in the above example if the client has no idea which door holds the treasure. However, this involves the server keeping track of every client's data which makes for higher resource usage on your end. Depending on the type of game, it might not be feasible.

And again, none of this is a fail safe against all hacks. e.g., A cheater could write a bot with superior reflexes that otherwise plays by all of the rules.

Some of this is needless worry if your game is small enough not to attract much attention. That's the ultimate security: Make a game that nobody wants to play and therefore nobody will bother to hack. ;)

All that said / in summary, here are some things you can do:

1. Store the high score in several variables, encrypting the actual contents in memory. That is, try to throw off the cheater who is looking at memory trying to find the score.
2. Use some sort of encryption when communicating with the server. You don't want the cheater to be able to simply sniff traffic and make a POST request... that's too easy.
3. Validate that the score makes sense given the amount of time played. You could periodically report the score to the server every five seconds, etc.
4. Make the client as dumb as possible... make the server authoritative.
5. If somebody posts an absolutely invalid score, ban that IP address and/or user account.
6. Pray that your game isn't very popular among hackers.

Answer (score 1):

The solution would probably be to use some form of encryption with a preshared key. Both the server and the flash app would need to use it with an algorithm to encode the request. You can still crack that fairly easily if all you want to do is repeat a request.

Here is some information based on AES which looks right to me:
http://www.lostinactionscript.com/blog/index.php/2009/11/29/aes-cryptography-for-actionscript-php/

PS: of course there are much more complex solutions involving an algorithm to determine the next preshared key based on some test, but this seems too much for a web game.

Answer (score 1):

The simple way for solving this problem is to pass as an extra argument (when posting to the page that save to db) which can be, for example, an md5 of the score plus a secret string.
Eg, if you send  as POST data  `score:12345` you can do something like `score:12345&key:119c8901b84be882530d60a45539705f`

In my example I calculated the md5 of `12345_secret`.
When you recive your data in the server you save them only if `md5(score+'_secret') == key`

Comment: Well, and a problem with this approach is that all scores match with the key, and thus if my friend got a score 9999 and I got a score of 10, I can just use the data from his request and get a score of 9999 as well. Using a variable, like a time parameter, stops this. But good answer, +1

Comment: yeah, of course, the more variable you use the more secure it become - includind a unique user id would of course be a good option

Answer (score 1):

Besides encrypting traffic, you might think about adding some "checkpoints" - once in a while, send some status from the client to the server. This might introduce some delays, but it would make it possible to follow client's status on the server. To make it totally (well, almost totally) secure, all decisions about every user's action should be made on the server. This won't work against complex bots that simulate user's actions, though it will be proof against "score submitters".

Comment: Well, this dosen't solve the problem if they can edit those submissions for "checkpoints"

Comment: @LostInTheCode, as you already wrote, nothing is foolproof. The safest solution would be to use strongly encrypted traffic for sending user's actions and making decisions on the server (rather than in flash game itself), though, even that would not be 100% secure.

Answer (score -1):

you can use [amfphp](http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/), it will hide your request.

Comment: I've added a link, but a bit more info would also have been helpful in this answer.

Comment: How does this hide the requests ? Is http://amfphp.sourceforge.net/ made with that technology ? If so, I've been able to see the requests :)